# PHP-FPM open_basedir vs chroot

Tags: php

From what I've seen chroot does the same as open_basedir except it also completely breaks a few PHP functions unless some trickery is made. Why do tutorials still use chroot instead of open_basedir? Is there a security implication to using the latter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a security implication.

open_basedir is a PHP implementation of chroot, so it's only applied on php scripts I/O. It will not be applied to system calls, i.e: system(), exec(), etc